# Android phones with(for?) those 5-inch screens

Tags: listening

Here's a video transcript from VOA news.
http://www.voanews.com/content/apple-introduces-two-bigger-more-powerful-iphone-models/2444114.html

00:24

> "I think there's a lot of people that got big-screen envy and switched away from Apple towards Android phones with those 5-inch screens, which are really amazing for reading books and looking at your calendar and web-reading.  If Apple can get into that category I think there's a lot of people waiting to switch back," said Ackerman.

I'm wondering if he really said "Android phones **with** those 5-inch screens".
It seems to me he said "Android phones **for** those 5-inch screens".

Comment: I hear *with*, not *for*.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that people switched away for five inch screens would be correct language, and it also is the correct meaning.  However, this is not an error.

Ackerman is using "those" to suggest a type of phone to the listener.  This is used when a speaker has forgotten a detail.  For example:

> You know those drinks, with the little umbrellas?
>
> - You mean Pina Coladas?
>
> You know those wheezy dogs, with the weird little faces?
>
> - Do you mean Pugs?
>
> You know that place that had the taco buffet?
>
> - Benito's!  I love that place, we haven't gone in ages.

If the speaker expects the listener will understand, or if it does not seem important to the story, sometimes they will skip the confirmation:

> You know those drinks, with the little umbrellas? I had six of those.
>
> - That's too many!
>
> You know those wheezy dogs, with the weird little faces? A lady brought one on the train and it stole my lunch.
>
> - That's awful!
>
> You know that place that had the taco buffet? It burned down last night.
>
> - Benito's?  No!

Ackerman says "I think there's a lot of people that got big-screen envy and switched away from Apple towards Android phones with those 5-inch screens", and if he had stopped there, the listener might respond with "Like the Samsung Note?" or another specific model.  However, in this case the speaker continued without that confirmation, since the story was already clear.

Because he did not specify a model, his story applies to any of the 5-inch Android devices that the listener might think of.  That makes the story faster to tell.  He also did not have to name his competition and give them free publicity.  Although this is an example of casual conversation, it is also a efficient and clever way to tell the story.

Comment: I'm asking whether he said **"with"** or **"for"**.
He said **with**, right?

Comment: He definitely said "with".  I only explained the use of "those" because it is important to understand why "with" makes sense in American English.  I am sorry that my answer wasn't clear.